# undefines values from input angular

Tags: angular

I'm loading data into a form, so if the user wants to change the data they should change the data into input and make a submit, but I have a problem, I can load the data and that's works, but at the momento of get the formControl.Value, I get undefined into the object and I don't understand why, this is my atempt:

Her I init my form and PosibleEditTeam is where I get the values for load.

```
  this.formEditTeam = this._fb.group({
        TeamName: new FormControl(this.PosibleEditTeam.Name, [Validators.required]),
        ColorMarkerTeam: new FormControl(this.PosibleEditTeam.ColorMark),
```

and my html form:

```
  <form *ngIf="isVisibleEditTeam" [formGroup]="formEditTeam">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="TeamName"
          ><i class="fa fa-users text-default"></i> Team name</label>
          <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-sm"
          id="TeamName"
          name="TeamName"
          formControlName="TeamName"
          placeholder="Inserta un nombre"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="ColorMarkerTeam"
          ><i class="fa fa-palette text-default"></i>
        Team</label
        >
        <input
          type="color"
          class="form-control form-control-sm"
          name="ColorMarkerTeam"
          formControlName="ColorMarkerTeam"
          id="ColorMarkerTeam"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

is something wrong with it?, if you think that it's ok and the problem is in another place, please ask for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced the scenario at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79pau6?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

e.g. I've got of team name using `this.formEditTeam.get("TeamName").value;` and it works just fine.

Please check the console log for more detail.